# DTC in SQL server 2008 R2 Clustering

Tags: sql-server-2008

I believe DTC is optional but cannot confirm it (can't find it on MSDN)

Why we need DTC (distributed transaction cordinator) when clusting a single instance (active passive scenario)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It is optional, though you will get a warning during setup.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180401182652/http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/what-exactly-is-msdtc-any-when-do-i-need-it/)

Here are [different config scenarios](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224211402/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/cindygross/archive/2009/02/22/how-to-configure-dtc-for-sql-server-in-a-windows-2008-cluster.aspx) for MSDTC.